# Unable to retrieve imported HTML document after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my server I have an HTML document called "creategame.html".

In a **separate** html document, I am importing "creategame.html" like so:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="import" href="<c:url value="/resources/html/creategame.html" />" id="create-game-forms">
...
</head>
```

(disregard the `<c:url>`thing, that is just syntax related to my view rendering engine).

On the very first page load, I am able to successfully retrieve the html document with:

```
var template = document.getElementById("create-game-forms").import;
```

("create-game-forms" is the id of the original `<link rel...>` tag that imports the html document)

And I am able to retrieve a tag from the imported html document with...

```
template.getElementById("my-custom-form-here")
```

(and then I can use javascript to inject an external snippet of html into my page)

However, after I reload the page...suddenly template becomes null...and calling template.getElementById() throws an error.

I am wondering if anyone knows why this is happening? Or if anyone could point me in the general direction of where the problem might be, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Ah so I figured this out. So it turns out that I was using the imported element before it was ready. The correct way to handle this was to wait for a "load" event like so:

```
var template = document.getElementById("create-game-forms");

template.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var imported_template = template.import;
  //do stuff with your imported template
});
```